# MUI Datagrid custom PDF export

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I have a Datagrid that shows Invoices. I can export to PDF by selecting the Print option. However, is it possible to customize that PDF outline to add a logo, headers, etc..?
If so, can anyone provide me with a tutorial or documentation or just point me in the right direction?